# Extension "plpythonu" is not supported by Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I am trying to install extension "plpython3u" that supports writing python in postgresql.

`CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;`

Error:

> SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: Extension "plpythonu" is not supported by
> Amazon RDS   Detail: Installing the extension "plpythonu" failed,
> because it is not on the list of extensions supported by Amazon RDS.
> Hint: Amazon RDS allows users with rds_superuser role to install
> supported extensions. See: SHOW rds.extensions;

Can you recomend a solution?

We are running the following version of postgresql:

> PostgreSQL 12.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1
> 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit

Comment: PL/Pyhton**U** is an untrusted extension because Python opens up the possibility to do _anything_ on the server (on operating system level). I highly doubt you will ever get this in a hosted environment

Comment: Right. One of the drawbacks of hosted databases.

Answer (score 5):

I opened a ticket with AWS and here is what they said:

> Please allow me to inform you that unfortunately, "plpythonu"
> extension is not on the list of supported extensions provided by
> Amazon RDS. In order to check the available supported extensions on
> your instance you can run the below queries or check the following
> link [1].
>
> => SHOW rds.extensions;
>
> The extension "plpythonu" in currently not be supported by RDS/Aurora
> as it would need access to the underlying filesystem. RDS as a managed
> service does not grant access to its underlying filesystem as it would
> break the ability to manage a database.
>
> I regret any inconvenience caused to you due to the limitation of the
> service. As I believe this is an important feature for you so after
> researching internally, I can confirm that there is already an
> existing feature request in place for supporting "plpythonu"
>
> So ,I went ahead and added your case to this feature request to have
> this functionality added.  The AWS service teams use these feature
> requests, in conjunction with other avenues of customer feedback, to
> plan and prioritize the features they deliver.

As you might understand, any new feature has to go through a review process and once approved it will go through a development cycle and rigorous testing before it can be rolled out to the public. And hence, I don't have an exact ETA on when this feature will be available.